# Create style for DataGridTextColumn (TextBlock)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textblock, datatrigger

I like to apply these style on the `ElementTemplate` of `DataGridTextColumn`. My Problem is my columns are bound to a collection. How can i access a property of my collection. Please look at "????" phrase in the source code.

I like to compare it against `Int32.Max`. These should be easy.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="HistoriesGridColumn">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="????" Value="Int32.Max">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just enter the propertyname inside binding attribute, don't care about visual studio warning.